# What methods exist to maintain precision with PHP integers of the order 10^18

Tags: php, integer, numbers

I'm writing a PHP script to use to explore the Collatz conjecture.

Long before I get to orders of magnitude such as 10^18, PHP switches to scientific notation and drops precision. I currently limit it to 10^12 because these values don't suffer from loss of precision. How should I go about handling larger integers without triggering this rounding effect?

Answer (score 1):

The BC Math functions would work for this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

For example:

```php
<?php

$number = "931386509544713451";
echo $number;
$steps = 0;

while ($number > 1) {
    if (bcmod($number, 2) == 0) {
        $number = bcdiv($number, 2);
    } else {
        $number = bcadd(bcmul($number, 3), 1);
    }
    echo ', ' . $number;
    $steps++;
}

echo ' [Steps=' . $steps . ']';

?>
```

You can run that at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e55e3c94d0920ff036f1c7feb8ce839f75e9df43

That will output the entire sequence for that starting number and give the correct amount of steps, which is 2283.

(*Disclaimer: I haven't written PHP for years, so this is almost certainly not a good example of PHP code. It's just for demonstrating the BC Maths functions.*)